# Failed to Decode Error?

Tags: polkadot, xcm, substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain

I was trying to `transfer nft` from `relay chain` to `parachain` through `transact` instruction of `Xcm`.
Here is snippet of code I am using

```js
Xcm(vec![Transact {
                    origin_kind:OriginKind::Xcm,
                    require_weight_at_most: Weight::from_parts(1_000, 1_000),
                    call: pallet_nfts::Call::<T, I>::create {
                        admin,
                        config
                    }
                    .encode()
                    .into(),
                }]),            )
             {  
                Ok((hash, cost)) => 
                     Self::deposit_event(Event::NftSent( hash, cost)),
                    
                Err(e) => 
                 Self::deposit_event(Event::NFTSendingError(e, )),          
}
```

Through this I was trying to call `create` function of `pallet-nfts` on `parachain`from relay chain, the code executed successfully and received event `NFTSent` on relay chain. The problem I faced on parachain is `Failed to Decode` .

Here is the function create of pallet-nfts

```js
pub fn create(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            admin: AccountIdLookupOf<T>,
            config: CollectionConfigFor<T, I>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let collection =
                NextCollectionId::<T, I>::get().unwrap_or(T::CollectionId::initial_value());
                frame_support::log::warn!("kuch bi ");
            let owner = T::CreateOrigin::ensure_origin(origin, &collection)?;
            frame_support::log::warn!("ye owner hai bhai {:?}",owner);
            let admin = T::Lookup::lookup(admin)?;
```

In this function we are passing three parameters, `Origin`, `admin`, `config`.My question here is how should I call this `transact instruction` so that it pass successfully it will be very helpful any one can guide me on this. Below is the code snippet of the transaction instruction that I am using.

```js
call: pallet_nfts::Call::<T, I>::create {
                        admin,
                        config
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/AlexD10S/xcm-playground/blob/master/src/mint_nft/mod.rs#L14) you can see an example that works for me.

```rs
let create_collection = relay_chain::RuntimeCall::Uniques(pallet_uniques::Call::<
            relay_chain::Runtime,
        >::create {
            collection: 1u32,
            admin: parachain_sovereign_account_id(1),
});
let mint = relay_chain::RuntimeCall::Uniques(pallet_uniques::Call::<relay_chain::Runtime>::mint {
                collection: 1u32,
                item: 1u32,
                owner: ALICE,
});

let create_collection_weight_estimation = Weight::from_parts(1_000_000_000, 10_000);
let mint_nft_weight_estimation = Weight::from_parts(1_000_000_000, 10_000);
let message = Xcm(vec![
            WithdrawAsset((Here, fees).into()),
            BuyExecution { fees: (Here, fees).into(), weight_limit: WeightLimit::Unlimited },
            Transact {
                origin_kind: OriginKind::SovereignAccount,
                require_weight_at_most: create_collection_weight_estimation,
                call: create_collection.encode().into(),
            },
            Transact {
                origin_kind: OriginKind::SovereignAccount,
                require_weight_at_most: mint_nft_weight_estimation,
                call: mint.encode().into(),
            },
        ]);
```

In your case you can skip the create_collection, if is already exist in the relay chain